# How to make slime-edit-definition work with non-compiled functions?

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime, clisp

I am using slime with clisp. If I try to use <kbd>M-.</kbd> on a function call while the file has never been compiled but only evaluated (by the mean of `slime-eval-last-expression' aka <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>) then I get that error message in return:

> cond: No known definition for: myfoo (in COMMON-LISP-USER)

While after compiling the function it seems to work. Is it a pre-condition to compile a file/function before having the possibility to navigate through it? If not, how to make it work?

Comment: yes it is, because slime needs to know which file to open for you to edit the definition